# Detect if running under launchd

Tags: macos, launchd

How do I detect that I'm running as a LaunchAgent under launchd on Mac OS X?

This is for a program (written in Go) that needs to restart when told to do so. If it's been started from a terminal or init script, it needs to do this by itself. If running under a service manager it should not attempt to restart but simply exit and be restarted by the manager.

For example, when running under Solaris SMF the environment variable `SMF_FMRI` is set, but I see nothing similar in launchd.

There are obvious workarounds (require a command line flag to be used or an environment variable to be set) but I'm interested in an "automatic" solution.

(This is not a duplicate of the similar sounding question [How to check if launchd has started the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706847/how-to-check-if-launchd-has-started-the-script))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your Parent Process Id (PPID) and compare it with the PID of launchd.

In the screen grab, you can see `launchd's` PID is 41840 (in red) and the PPIDs of `mdflagwriter`, `distnoted` and `cfprefsd` (in blue) match that number, so they were launched by `launchd`.

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I hope so. I have never tried it on OSX, but that's what I always used to do on Solaris, IRIX, HP-UX. Maybe add a comment if it goes well, so we all learn something!