# Service launcher status always shows stopped on macOS

Tags: install4j

I have generated a service launcher in install4j and installed it on macOS using the install service action. When I execute `<launcher> status` in the terminal, it always says stopped even though the service has started. The behavior is the same if I launch the service using `<launcher> start` and then query for status.

`<launcher> stop` also does have any effect on the service that is running.

How do I get this to work on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, you have to use `launchctl` to control services:

[How to check if launchd has started the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706847/how-to-check-if-launchd-has-started-the-script)